# Simplifying $\cos^2\theta\sin\phi+\sin^2\theta\cos\phi$ or $\sin^2\theta\sin\phi-\cos^2\theta\cos\phi$

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone see a way to simplify one of these expressions? It looks so neat, there has got to be a way! :D

$$\cos^2\theta\sin\phi+\sin^2\theta\cos\phi \tag1$$
or
$$\sin^2\theta\sin\phi-\cos^2\theta\cos\phi \tag2$$

I've tried identities like the following, but am only making whole thing more complicated...

$$\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x \qquad \sin^2x=\frac12(1-\cos2x)$$

Comment: These are already simple. Seems hard to do anything better.

Comment: It would look even neater if you put a backslash before "sin" and "cos". Like this: $\sin(\phi)$ instead of $sin(\phi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\phi)+\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\phi)=$

$=\left(1-\sin^2(\theta)\right)\sin(\phi)+\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\phi)=$

$=\sin(\phi)+\sin^2(\theta)\big(\cos(\phi)-\sin(\phi)\big)=$

$=\sin(\phi)+\sin^2(\theta)\big(\cos(\phi)+\cos(\phi+\frac{\pi}2)\big)=$

$=\sin(\phi)+2\sin^2(\theta)\big(\cos(\phi+\frac{\pi}4)\cos(\frac{\pi}4)\big)=$

$=\sin(\phi)+\sqrt2\sin^2(\theta)\cos\left(\phi+\frac{\pi}4\right)\;.$

I cannot do anything better than it.

Comment: @ella: This result has lost any symmetry. It is ugly.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my result is not symmetric, but can you simplify that expression without losing symmetry?

Comment: @a: I already said no, and I don't see any simplification here.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions are pretty simple. You *could* write
$$\begin{align}
f :=\; \cos^2\theta\sin\phi+\sin^2\theta\cos\phi &= \phantom{-}\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \left(\sin\left(\frac\pi4+\phi\right)- \cos2\theta\sin\left(\frac\pi4-\phi\right)\right) \\[6pt]
g:=\; \sin^2\theta\sin\phi-\cos^2\theta\cos\phi &= -\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \left(\sin\left(\frac\pi4-\phi\right)+\cos2\theta\sin\left(\frac\pi4+\phi\right)\right)
\end{align}$$ but those are not what I'd call "simpler". (That said, if your context lends some significance to the quantity $\phi\pm\pi/4$, then there could be some benefit here.)

Depending upon your needs, it could be useful to write them as
$$\begin{align}
f &= \phantom{-}\cos^2\theta\cos\phi(\tan^2\theta+\tan\phi)\\[4pt]
g &= -\cos^2\theta\cos\phi(1-\tan^2\theta\tan\phi)
\end{align}$$
Those may-or-may-not seem better, but note that the ratio $f/g$ looks an *awful lot* like (the negative of) the angle-addition formula for tangent ... if only we had $\tan^2\theta=\tan\psi$ for some $\psi$. But in that case, we'd have
$$\begin{align}
\cos^2\theta &= \frac{1}{1+\tan^2\theta} = \frac{1}{1+\tan\psi}=\frac{\cos\psi}{\sin\psi+\cos\psi}=\frac{\cos\psi}{\sqrt{2}\sin(\psi+\frac\pi4)} \\[6pt]
\sin^2\theta &= \frac{\sin\psi}{\sqrt{2}\sin(\psi+\frac\pi4)}
\end{align}$$
whereupon, we'd obtain
$$f=\frac{\sin(\psi+\phi)}{\sqrt2\sin(\psi+\frac\pi4)} \qquad\qquad
g = -\frac{\cos(\psi+\phi)}{\sqrt2\sin(\psi+\frac\pi4)}$$
Those are also not necessarily "simpler" than the original forms, and the $\tan^2\theta\to\tan\psi$ re-parameterization may not be appropriate for your particular needs, but they seem pretty neat to me. :)

We couuld even take it further, defining $\psi':=\psi+\pi/4$ and $\phi':=\phi-\pi/4$:
$$f = \frac{\sin(\psi'+\phi')}{\sqrt2\sin\psi'} \qquad\qquad g = -\frac{\cos(\psi'+\phi')}{\sqrt2\sin\psi'}$$
but there's a danger of veering too far outside the context of your investigation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit on my questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\cos t = \dfrac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}, \sin t = \dfrac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}, t = \theta, \phi$.

Comment: Why do you think it makes things simpler ?

Comment: I know but why do you think it makes things simpler ? Did you try ?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't think translating sin^2 with Euler is useful here. ill have to square my imaginary e-functions too. i believe it will get messy.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.